# How non-native Russian language course will approach to deciphering the phrase "Косил косой косой косой"?

Tags: перевод, падежи, склонение, морфология

There's a perfectly valid phrase in Russian: "Косил косой косой косой". It contains three completely identically-looking words at the end and the first one is a different declension of others. I am native Russian so I understand what this phrase means and my question is not about that.

Is there any problem for non-russian speaking teacher to explain to curious pupil the meaning of the above?
What topics of Russian language are a must for comprehending the above?
Let's say you're that teacher; how you'll approach in explaining the above?

Comment: The phrase has at least two different meanings.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds _A cockeyed man scythed with an askew scythe_. As Russian word-ordering is free there could be variants which one "косой" is an adjective, a noun in nominative or a noun in instrumental.

Comment: @Anixx Can you please tell me second *meaning*, different from what user4419802 said above? ;) Not just different word ordering.

Comment: косой косой may mean skewed squint-eyed.

Comment: "Косой" can also mean "a hare", or "with a braid" (instead of a scythe), or "on a [spit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spit_%28landform%29)"...

Comment: It's quite hard to mow with a braid, and it's quite hard to imagine "skewed braid", so no native speakers will seriously consider the meaning "a squint-eyed man mowed with a skewed braid", or "a hare mowed with a skewed braid".

Comment: @Anixx Oh, I got it now what is a second meaning, with hare. :) It's not *that* different from "squint-eyed" one, though.

Comment: Also, _косить_ can mean 'to pretend disabled, to avoid doing the job one has to do,' and also 'earn [money],' which add even more meanings to that sentence.

Comment: @YellowSky It doesn't matter how many meaning a word have if it doesn't fit into the overall sentence! How can you "slack with an askew skytche", be you a hare or squint-eyed?  My intent was to look only at the meaningful translation of this sentence.

Comment: It all depends on what 'meaningful' is for you. "A squint-eyed avoided to be recruited [to the army] by [wearing] a crooked plait [so that to look an idiot]" is a pretty meaningful sentence. Phrases like 'a woman clothed with the sun' or 'chariots of fire' may also seem meaningless to some, still all of the European civilization is built on them, they're from the Bible.

Comment: @YellowSky Getting a skew pigtail on the head to avoid being recruited to the Army? You've made my day.

Comment: @user4419802 - In the post-Soviet countries military service was mandatory, and the main way to avoid it was pretending to be mentally ill. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky Sure, I know. Yet I never heard about any skew pigtails helping to do that ;)

Comment: @YellowSky BTW. Any person suffering of strabismus has an offical exemption of conscription, so one doesn't need to cheat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original phrase can be extended/modified:

> Лопоухий косой за песчаной косой пал под острой косой косой бабы с
>   косой.

The updated phrase uses the word "косой" with 5 different meanings. Extra words in the phrase help a non-native speaker to identify the meaning of each "косой" instance. Translation:

> - лопоухий косой - lop-eared hare
> - за песчаной косой - beyond a sandbank
> - пал под острой косой - fell under a sharp scythe
> - косой бабы - of a cross-eyed woman
> - с косой - with a braid

Once that "explained" phrase is picked apart and understood by a student, then student would need to know at least two more meanings of the word:

> - косой - skewed; crooked
> - косой - cross-eyed man (as a noun)

Then a student can try to make sense of the original phrase:

> Косил косой косой косой

There is a possibility of a double meaning here. The subject in this sentence could be a man, but in a context of a fairy-tale it could be a hare.

**UPDATE:**
Another aspect of the problem, in addition to the many meanings of word "косой", is the exact meaning of each word. Russian grammar is flexible and allows words to be moved around in a sentence. A teacher may list the following three (possibly more) word-order sequences:

> - Verb / subject / adjective modifying object / object - Cut / cross-eyed man / with a crooked / scythe
> - Verb / adjective modifying object / object / subject - Cut / with a crooked / scythe / cross-eyed man
> - Verb / object / adjective modifying subject / subject - Cut / with scythe / cross-eyed / cross-eyed man

In the last example adjective and the subject restate the obvious (repeat themselves).  That usage is unlikely in practice.  The first two examples  deliver the exact same idea in spite of individual "косой" words taking different meanings.

Answer (score 6):

**"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."** is a grammatically correct sentence in American English, used as an example of how homonyms and homophones can be used to create complicated linguistic constructs.

The approach will be [**same**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: It's a nice hint int the direction which can give an answer, but not an answer.

Comment: I must say that buffalo example completely blew my mind. Never seen word "buffalo" used as a synonym for "to bully".

Comment: Говорит попугай попугаю:
    Я тебя, попугай, попугаю!
    Попугаю в ответ попугай:
    Попугай, попугай Попугай!

Comment: "Математика интересует физика". There is also the similar thing in Chinese https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den